# Return nested JSON item that has multiple instances

Tags: python, json

So i am able to return almost all data, except i am not able to capture something like this:

```
 "expand": "schema"
  "issues": [
    {
      "expand": "<>",
      "id": "<>",
      "self": "<>",
      "key": "<>",
      "fields": {
        "components": [
          {
            "self": "<>",
            "id": "1",
            "name": "<>",
            "description": "<>"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "expand": "<>",
      "id": "<>",
      "self": "<>",
      "key": "<>",
      "fields": {
        "components": [
          {
            "self": "<>",
            "id": "<>",
            "name": "<>"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
```

I want to return a list that contains both of the 'name's for 'components', i have tried using:

```
 list((item['fields']['components']['name']) for item in data['issues'])
```

but i get a type error saying `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str` when i try to `Print()` the above line of code

Also, if i could get some explanation of what this type error means, and what "list" is trying to do that means that it is not a "str" that would be appreciated

EDIT:

```
url = '<url>'
r = http.request('GET', url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(r.data.decode('utf-8'))

print([d['name'] for d in item['fields']['components']] for item in data['issues'])
```

Comment: `item['fields']['components']` is a list. You're treating it like a dictionary.

Comment: Just for clarification, why is this a dicitonary by adding list()? the data returned from `list((item['fields']['components']['name']) for item in data['issues'])`  is surrounded with " [ ] " and from reading up on it, it says that this would be considered a list

Comment: The value of `item['fields']['components']` is a list: `[{"self": "<>", "id": "<>", "name": "<>"}]`. The first element of that list is another dictionary in which you can access `name`. So the correct way to access the name would be:

`item['fields']['components'][0]['name']`  -- I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the commenter points out you're treating the list like a dictionary, instead this will select the `name` fields from the dictionaries in the list:

```
list((item['fields']['components'][i]['name'] for i, v in enumerate(item['fields']['components'])))
```

Or simply:

```
[d['name'] for d in item['fields']['components']]
```

You'd then need to apply the above to all the items in the iterable.

**EDIT: Full solution to just print the `name` fields, assuming that "issues" is a key in some larger dictionary structure:**

```
for list_item in data["issues"]: # issues is a list, so iterate through list items
    for dct in list_item["fields"]["components"]: # each list_item is a dictionary
        print(dct["name"]) # name is a field in each dictionary
```

Comment: The brackets really can be omitted as it's just a list comprehension.  `[d['name'] for d in item['fields']['components']]`

Comment: Why is it when i try to `print()` this line of code it comes back as a generator object in my terminal and not with the acutal names?

Comment: Can you post the code of what is producing the generator object?

Comment: Just did, Check EDIT

Comment: Try this instead: `print([[d['name'] for d in v['components']] for k, v in data['issues'].items()])`

Comment: i got this error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: Are you able to post a full sample of the format of `data`? It seems like `data` is a dictionary, with some of its contents as lists and some as dictionaries; which will determine how to select items from it. But the sample you provided starts at the level of `fields`

Comment: Above is the sample that should show it, the whole thing is a list of 'issues' which holds a 'fields' dictionary then a components list.  Please tell me if i'm using the 'list' or 'dictionary' terms incorrectly

Comment: Ok it's still not possible for me to copy your data example, but assuming that "issues" is a dictionary key from some larger dictionary I have updated my answer to show a solution.