# Difference between dictionaries and lists with item['data] vs list(item['data])

Tags: python, python-3.x

So on my last post i was downvoted because of i misunderstood the differences and wanted to know the differences between these two.

i was told that `item['data'] for item in data ['issues']` is a list.

When ever i `print(item['data'] for item in data ['issues'])` to my terminal it came back with a generator object instead of a list of data. like so 
`<generator object <genexpr> at 0x7ff125beb410>`

Also i was told that `list(item['data'] for item in data ['issues'])` meant i was treating it as a dictionary. But from my understanding of dictionaries, each value is paired with a key, and this data returned in my terminal with `print(list(item['data'] for item in data ['issues']))`, looks like a list to me.  Here is what would be returned:

```
['20898', '20796', '20781', '20707', '20705', '20561']
```

**So my question:**

Why is `list(item['data'] for item in data ['issues'])` considered a dictionary and `item['data'] for item in data ['issues']` is considered a list when the data returned is a generator object and the other returned with what looks like a list?

There could be something i'm missing about what they are trying to tell me so this is my other post for reference [Return nested JSON item that has multiple instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53655301/return-nested-json-item-that-has-multiple-instances/53655396#53655396)

Comment: I also added a comment to your other question to help you understand why your usage of subscript `['name']` meant that `item['fields']['components']` was being used like a dictionary when it was actually a list. If my answer and comment help you, do upvote and consider marking the answer as accepted answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First, let's create some sample data (a dictionary):

```
data = {'issues': [{'data': '20898'}, {'data': '20796'}, {'data': '20781'}, {'data': '20707'}, {'data': '20705'}, {'data': '20561'}]}
```

The expression below will create a generator object, thus it will only be iterated on once to yield each element in the object exactly once:

```
(item['data'] for item in data ['issues'])
```

Returns:

```
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x0000026BBE5ECB88>
```

Opposed to a list comprehension, which will actually return a list that can be iterated on multiple times (the following two statements are equivalent):

```
list(item['data'] for item in data ['issues'])

[item['data'] for item in data ['issues']]
```

Both return:

```
['20898', '20796', '20781', '20707', '20705', '20561']
```

Neither of these outputs are dictionaries. Your `data` that is supplied as an input to these statements is a dictionary. Basically, use a generator expression if all you're doing is iterating once. If you want to store and use the generated results, then you're probably better off with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax for list comprehension is correct and the alternate syntax would be: `[item['data'] for item in data['issues']]` - i.e. surrounding the expression with square brackets.

To clarify, the following expression is a generator expression:

```
item['data'] for item in data ['issues']
```

It becomes a list only when you wrap it in `list()` or `[]`, as follows:

```
list(item['data'] for item in data ['issues'])
```

Or,

```
[item['data'] for item in data ['issues']]
```

In your other question, it's mentioned that you treat `item['fields']['components']` as a dictionary because you try to subscript `['name']` to get a value. One subscripts dictionaries by keys, not lists.

If you notice carefully, the value of `item['fields']['components']` is wrapped in square brackets too, which means it is a list; and that list contains a dictionary as the first element which as a key called `name`.